# Команда для удаления всех вложенных ключей и параметров реестра

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Имею в реестре такой путь:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Devo Soft\SMS Hero\Services
```

Цель - удалить всё, что находится внутри ключа "Services", включая вложенные в него ключи и параметры.

В связи с этим создал вот такой bat-файл:

```
REG DELETE HKCU\SOFTWARE\Devo Soft\SMS Hero\Services
```

Но он, к сожалению, не работает.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так? А вообще здорово, если кинете в меня правильным вариантом команды.

Если команда будет удалять в том числе и родительский ключ "Services", то это не проблема.

Comment: Записать `[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Devo Soft\SMS Hero\Services]` в `1.reg`?

Comment: Всё отлично! Спасибо за идею с файлом реестра. Уже нашел команду для его применения.
Хорошего вам дня :)